# Insert the post title inside my post

Tags: php, wordpress, post, insert, title

I would like to insert the current post title inside a Wordpress post using PHP.

Here my code:

```
<?php $title = get_the_title($post); 
single_post_title( 'Produit concerné : ' );
echo $title; ?>
```

It is not displaying nothing. Can you tell me where I did a mistake?

Thanks for your help,

Florian

Comment: *"Do I shall put a "echo" somewhere?"* - Maybe, that or return it. There isn't enough code here.

Comment: I saw this code here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_post_title

Comment: keep reading it and try out something from the examples, which I'm sure contains some. You either echo or return a method.

Comment: Do I need to configure something in the functions of my theme or this function is native?

Comment: I found the solution! Here the code:
<?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?>

I used the WP Insert Code plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-insert-code/
I added the code inside the plugin, then I'm using a shortcode on my post page to display it.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Gread, glad to hear it. You know that Stack lets you post your own answer. It will let you accept it at a later date. I suggest you do post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! Here the code:

```
 <?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?>
```

I used the WP Insert Code plugin to insert the php code in my post, here the link: wordpress.org/plugins/wp-insert-code

I added the code inside the plugin and its generated a shortcode that I can use easily on my post page to display it.

Cheers